# SSRS - Using iff(Instr(Fields! to find certain text in a string

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I'm struggling (spending LOTS of time trying to figure this out) to make an iff statement work in SSRS/Report Builder.

I'm pulling a VARCHAR into a report. In the VARCHAR, consists of lots of words/text.

I'm trying to colour this textbox if this VARCHAR string contains the word "red" or "amber" or "green".

If it does find either of these words in the VARCHAR string, I would like it to colour the textbox the same colour as the text it's looking for.

If it finds "red" in the VARCHAR, the textbox becomes red in colour, etc.

I've looked on google and youtube lots and have found two potential solutions:

- iff(Fields!note.value.contains("red"), "red", "white")

-Above I believe should look for "red" in the VARCHAR string and then fill the textbox red if it matches or white if no match?

- iff(InStr()<0, [true], [false])

The second option I have no idea how this would work. I apologise that my syntax for vba is awful. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I'm trying to learn SSRS and/or Report Builder on the job.

Please note I'm using Report Builder ver 15 OR Visual Studio 2019.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `Tostring.Contains()` like this... (I've used SWITCH rather than nested `IIF`s as it's cleaner in my opinion.

```
=SWITCH(
       Fields!AddressLine1.Value.ToString.Contains("Street"), "Red",
       Fields!AddressLine1.Value.ToString.Contains("Road"), "Green",
       Fields!AddressLine1.Value.ToString.Contains("Ave"), "Orange",
       True, Nothing)
```

The last `True` acts like an else. I've also used `Nothing` which is the default 'transparent'

I used this on a test dataset and applied the expression to the last column, here are the results....

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. Would it be possible for you to explain the SWITCH syntax to me? Can't thank you enough for this. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, `SWITCH()` works in pairs, 1st an expression to evaluate and if it returns 'True' it returns the 2nd expression and then stops, if not it then evaluates the  3rd expression and if that's true returns the 4th and so on, the final `True` is there so if all other text are `false` the last one is always true (so it acts like an `ELSE`). Read this for more details. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16. Can you please mark the answer as accepted (check mark under the vote up/down buttons)

Comment: I have 1 more question - how on earth would you use this for an external dataset?

i.e =Lookup(Fields!Primary.Value, Fields!Secondary.Value, Fields!note.Value, "DataSetName")

Comment: I've never tried this but I would expect you could do `=LOOKUP(x,y,z, dataset).ToString("something")`

Comment: Thanks, Alan. Going to try and use your last comment to get this working on another dataset.